# Assembly language (EmbestIDE) - Why is there no change in register values?

Tags: assembly

I wrote the following assembly language code to implement bubble sort in a 10 data array, each data being 16 bits long. There is no compilation error, but the register values don't change when I execute line by line.

This is the 'build' window when I compile my program:

```
.global _start
   2               
   3               .text 
   4               _start:
   5 0000 0910A0E3  mov r1, #9
   6 0004 0920A0E3  mov r2, #9
   7               
   8               loop:
   9               
  10 0008 28309FE5  ldr r3,=dat1
  11 000c 0120A0E1  mov r2,r1
  12               
  13               loop2:
  14               
  15 0010 B040D3E1  ldrh r4,[r3]
  16 0014 B250D3E1  ldrh r5,[r3,#2]
  17 0018 050054E1  cmp r4,r5
  18 001c 005083C5  strgt r5,[r3]
  19 0020 024083C5  strgt r4,[r3,#2]
  20 0024 023083E2  add r3,r3,#2
  21 0028 012052E2  subs r2,r2,#1
  22 002c 0200001A  bne loop2
  23               
  24 0030 011051E2  subs r1,r1,#1
  25 0034 0000001A  bne loop
  26               
  27 0038 00000000  .data 
  28               dat1:
  29 0000 8597      .hword 0x9785
  30 0002 29A8      .hword 0xa829
  31 0004 3412      .hword 0x1234
  32 0006 6382      .hword 0x8263
  33 0008 34B2      .hword 0xb234
  34 000a 8709      .hword 0x0987
  35 000c 2314      .hword 0x1423
  36 000e 1792      .hword 0x9217
  37 0010 1111      .hword 0x1111
  38 0012 2143      .hword 0x4321
  39               
  40               
  41               .end
ARM GAS  C:\EmbestIDE\Bin\proj1\order.s    page 2
```

Is it something to do with where the instructions are stored? :/

Comment: Register values must change, at least `pc` must, as it must show the next instruction after stepping over previous one. That "build window" looks as listing, that's a neat thing to have for checking how the resulting machine code looks in output file. But after you execute it, the disassembly window in debugger shows real memory and instructions, so you should rather watch that, in case there's some unexpected memory overwrite or you jump by accident somewhere outside of your code. If you have some working example, try to compare it in debugger, what looks different after loading it.

Comment: Yes only pc changes.